# How do I change a REG_DWORD value's base from Hexadecimal to Decimal via PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: .net, powershell, registry

For a private preview tool provided by Microsoft, a registry value needs to be set to Type REG_DWORD value 46, then change the Base from hexadecimal to decimal. Here is a portion of the documentation I am referring to:

1. Use the Edit menu or right-click to create a new DWORD (32-bit)
   Value    and name it  WUfBDF (note the only lowercase letter in this
   name is the 3rd ‘f’ and all the rest are uppercase).
2. Next, right-click on the new value and select the Modify… option.
   Make sure to choose the Decimal base and set the value to 46.

I am creating a Proactive remediation script to push out to a group of machines that need this Reg key/item for the preview tool to work.

```
$regkeyPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
$regEntry = "WUfBDF"
$desiredValue = 46

function createRegEntry($path, $entry, $value){
    write-output "Remediating registry entry."
    if(test-path -Path $path){
        write-output "$path exists. Setting $entry"
        Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $entry -Value $value -Type DWord -force | out-null
    }else{
        New-Item -Path $Path -Force
        New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $entry -Value $value -PropertyType DWord -force | out-null
    }
}

createRegEntry $regkeyPath $regEntry $desiredValue
```

I read the Set-ItemProperty documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.2) from Microsoft Documentation and it seems that when creating a REG-DWORD value its Base defaults to hex and has to manually be altered. Any way to change it to REG_DWORD with the Base as Decimal

Comment: The base is just a display thing. It's not stored in the registry, just used for display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "base" option in the regedit UI is a convenience for the user. The instructions could just as easily have said "set base to Hexadecimal and enter 2e" - they're both the same number. Sometimes it's just easier to work with a hex number - e.g. `0xF000` (hex) instead of `61440` (decimal) or vice versa.

In fact, if you set the dialog to Decimal, enter 46 and then change to Hexadecimal you'll see the "Value data" change to 2e automatically...

[image]

[image]

And it shows *both* values in the main details pane:

[image]

Similarly, when writing your PowerShell code you could write `$desiredValue = 46` or `$desiredValue = 0x2E` and get the same result. They're both representations of the same number - one decimal and one hexadecimal - it just depends on your preference which format you use.

Comment: Your right, although Microsoft documentation for this Personal preview tool explicitly states to change to a decimal value (probably, as you mention, convenience), I was able to add the devices to the policy by pushing the reg settings out via Proactive remediation script.

Comment: I guess they wanted to be explicit in the documented steps, so they had to choose *one* or the other, and they chose decimal.